# Как получать от пользователя формат str?

Tags: python-3.x, aiogram

Пользователь должен вести слово "go" но код к сожалению не корректный, помогите пожалуйста.

```
@dp.message_handler(state=InputWhatever.x)
async def get_number(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    if message.text.isalpha():
        if str(message.text) = "go":
            await InputWhatever.x2.set()
            async with state.proxy() as data:
                data["number"] = int(message.text)
                data['user_array'] = []
            await message.answer("Правильно")
            await message.answer("text2")
        else:
            await message.answer("Введите число больше 0!")
    else:
        await message.answer("Введите кол-во!")
```

Answer (score 0):

Оказывается нужно было к знаку = поставить <.
Мда... я буду долго изучать этот язык

```
@dp.message_handler(state=InputWhatever.x)
async def get_number(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    if message.text.isalpha():
        if str(message.text) <= "go":
            await InputWhatever.x2.set()
            async with state.proxy() as data:
                data["number"] = int(message.text)
                data['user_array'] = []
            await message.answer("Правильно")
            await message.answer("text2")
        else:
            await message.answer("Возможно не тот регистр")
    else:
        await message.answer("no int")
```

Comment: туда не нужен знак меньше, нужно два равно ==

Comment: это оператор равности

Comment: А можете дать подсказку к этому коду, мне нужно в место "Go" написать Русскими буквами "Зона". Любой Русский текст не работает в телеграмботе, а Английский читает без ошибок. Как исправить?